# MYSQL Trigger() vs. Delete permanently

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have two tables as below:

1. Table `Job_Announcement` used to store information about Job, defined as below:

   `+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
   | Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
   +-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
   | job_id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
   | job_title       | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
   | category        | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
   | term            | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
   | num_experiences | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
   | num_hiring      | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
   | Salary          | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
   | qualification   | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
   | location        | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
   | gender          | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
   | job_content     | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
   | job_requirement | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
   | publish_date    | date         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
   | close_date      | date         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
   | contact_info    | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
   | userid          | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
   | publish         | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
   +-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+`
2. And Table `job_announcement_deleted`, used to store deleted record from table `job_announcement`

   `+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
   | Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
   +--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
   | job_id       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
   | job_title    | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
   | category     | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
   | job_content  | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
   | publish_date | date         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
   | close_date   | date         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
   | userid       | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
   | publish      | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
   +--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+`

In order to move deleted record from `job_announcement` table to `job_announcement_deleted` table, I defined `trigger` definition in `phpmyadmin` like this:

**Trigger Name:** before_delete_job

**Table:** job_announcement

**Time:** BEFORE

**Event:** Delete

**Definition:** 

`BEGIN
INSERT INTO job_announcement_deleted VALUES(old.job_id,old.job_title,old.category,old.job_content,old.publish_date,old.close_date,old.userid,old.publish);
END`

**Definer:** root@localhost

The trigger event `before_delete_job` is working fine that the deleted record moved to table `job_announcement_deleted`.

My problem is if I want to restore deleted record back to table `job_announcement`, I define similar trigger definition event like above, ex. `job_announcement_restore` for tale `job_announcement_deleted` however, how can I do if I want to delete record permanently from `job_announcement_deleted`? because I want user have options either to restore it or to deleted permanantly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the restore just do the reverse process you did for delete (sending data from `job_announcement_deleted` to `job_announcement`)

For the perma delete you just have to get the job_id field, since it's auto-incremeneted making it unique for every job.

After you acquire job_id from the user (e.g if he clicks delete from this row you extract job_id from that row), just use `DELETE FROM` like this :

```
DELETE FROM job_announcement_deleted WHERE job_id = @job_id
```

(where @job_id will be the one you acquired earlier in the process)

Also, you shouldn't be sending job_id to the `job_announcement_deleted` table, since the field is auto-increment, meaning it'll add a new value (incremented by 1 by default) for that field, so there are no duplicates for that field. You just destroy the meaning of auto-increment by doing that, specially since primary key must be a unique value. You could have trouble later on with the database if you get duplicate values for that field, so I suggest you just leave that field unfilled so auto-increment can do it's job.

Comment: @MirzS, I'm still not so clear since I already defined trigger in table 'job_announcement_deleted' it is supposed that every deleting record will be restored back to table 'job_announcement' not delete permanently. How to differentiate them ?

Comment: You can add more than 1 trigger and define when they are fired/executed. So I guess for perma deleting you don't even need a trigger, you can use one like after_delete on table job_announcement_deleted to insert maybe name of the deleted job into log file with the name of the user who deleted it. Triggers can be defined for anything, insert, drop, select, not just delete. You can look up [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/create-multiple-triggers-for-the-same-trigger-event-and-action-time/) for creating multiple tirggers for the same event and action time.